# Unable to change font-family while using fontawsome in project

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have a menu, I want to insert fontawsome icons in the menu. I have following code

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <a href="#" ><span class="fa fa-home">Home</span></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 div a {
  font-size:50px;
  display:block;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:none;
  background-color:green;
  font-family:'Segoe UI';
}
```

I want menu items to appear as block so that user can click on icons to open link, To achieve that I have to insert icon inside `<a>` tag. But after doing so I am unable to change font-family. I can change size and color but can't change family. I have tried many solutions but nonthing happened.
Is there anyway to change font-family?

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s96tz63b/3/)

Comment: Avoid use of licensed fonts in HTML documents! Try to only use shared or open fonts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to wrap any text with your font-awesome html element, so what you should have is:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" ><span class="fa fa-home"></span>Home</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because in your mark up, you are enclosing the Home text inside the `span` with the `fa fa-home` classes, so the css of the font-awesome is taking precedence over your `div a` font selection.

```
<div>
    <span class="fa fa-home"></span><a href="#" >Home</a>
</div>


div {
 background-color:green;
 display:inline-block;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:50px;
}
div a {
  font-size:50px;
  display:inline-block;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-family:'arial';
  color:#fff;
}
```